# Performing operations on a processed int vector

Tags: c++, vectors

This question came from *C++ Primer* 5th edition:

> Q: Read a set of integers into a vector. Print the sum of each pair of
>   adjacent elements. Change your program so that it prints the sum of
>   the first and last elements, followed by the sum of the second and
>   second-tolast, and so on.

I was just wondering if there is any way to improve my solution.

Part 1:

```
int main(){

    vector<int> intVector;
    int number;
    while (cin >> number){
        intVector.push_back(number);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < intVector.size(); i++){
        int k;
        k = intVector[i] + intVector[i + 1];
        cout << k << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Part 2:

```
int main(){

    vector<int> intVector;
    int number;
    while (cin >> number) {
        intVector.push_back(number);
    }
    int sizeOfIntVector = intVector.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfIntVector / 2; i++){
        int k;
        k = intVector[i] + intVector[sizeOfIntVector - 1 - i];
        cout << k << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things that I want to point out.
First of all, I think that this part of code has an error

```
for (int i = 0; i < intVector.size(); i++){
    int k;
    k = intVector[i] + intVector[i + 1];
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

I think it will crash when `i = intVector.size() - 1` and you are trying to access `intVector[i + 1]`. Try looping till `i < intVector.size() - 1`

Secondly, your second solution works fine when `sizeOfIntVector` is even and there is nothing to worry about. But when it is odd you are missing one sum to print. So I guess it should be something like this

```
int sizeOfIntVector = intVector.size();
int sumsToPrintCount = sizeOfIntVector / 2;
if (sizeOfIntVector % 2 == 1){
    sumsToPrintCount++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < sumsToPrintCount; i++){
    int k;
    k = intVector[i] + intVector[sizeOfIntVector - 1 - i];
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Never use `using namespace std;`. 
   Some reasons why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
2. Part 1 is fine other than the error [Bogdan Yarema](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/96664/bogdan-yarema) pointed out. I would personally just start at 1 instead thought.

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i < intVector.size(); i++){

       int k = intVector[i] + intVector[i - 1];
       cout << k << endl;
   }
   ```
3. In case the size of the vector is odd and the element in center should be added to himself (as [Bogdan Yarema](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/96664/bogdan-yarema) pointed out as swell), it would be better to get the ceiling of `intVector.size() / 2`

   ```
   int half = (intVector.size() + 1 )/ 2;
   int last = intVector.size() - 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {

       int k = intVector[i] + intVector[last - i];
       std::cout << k << std::endl;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For reading the input, I'd at least consider something along this line:

```
std::istream_iterator<int> input(std::cin), end;
std::vector<int> { input, end };
```

I'm not sure whether I really recommend it for this case, but the standard library has `std::adjacent_difference`. Despite "difference" in the name, it can actually carry out an arbitrary operation on adjacent items in a collection, so we *could* implement the first addition loop as:

```
std::adjacent_difference(in.begin(), in.end(), 
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"),
    [](int a, int b) { return a + b; });
```

This does have one other oddity: it produces the first element of the input un-changed, then that's followed by the results for the pairs of elements.

For the second loop, we can use `std::transform`, (without the questionable details in the preceding):

```
auto mid = (in.size() + 1) / 2;

std::transform(in.begin(), std::next(in.begin(), mid),
    in.rbegin(),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"),
    std::plus<int>());
```

As I said, I'm uncertain whether I can really recommend using `adjacent_difference` to compute adjacent sums. Using `transform` instead of the second loop seems to me like a clear win though.